# How to use XQuery to transform consecutive tags into nested tags or table

Tags: xml, xpath, xquery, xquery-3.0

I have an XML file with consecutive tags instead of nested tags, like the following:

```
<title>
    <subtitle>
        <topic att="TopicTitle">Topic title 1</topic>
        <content att="TopicSubtitle">topic subtitle 1</content>
        <content att="Paragraph">paragraph text 1</content>
        <content att="Paragraph">paragraph text 2</content>
        <content att="TopicSubtitle">topic subtitle 2</content>
        <content att="Paragraph">paragraph text 1</content>
        <content att="Paragraph">paragraph text 2</content>

        <topic att="TopicTitle">Topic title 2</topic>
        <content att="TopicSubtitle">topic subtitle 1</content>
        <content att="Paragraph">paragraph text 1</content>
        <content att="Paragraph">paragraph text 2</content>
        <content att="TopicSubtitle">topic subtitle 2</content>
        <content att="Paragraph">paragraph text 1</content>
        <content att="Paragraph">paragraph text 2</content>
    </subtitle>
</title>
```

I'm using XQuery in BaseX and I want to convert it to a table with the following columns:

```
Title      Subtitle      TopicTitle      TopicSubtitle      Paragraph
Irrelevant Irrelevant    Topic title 1   Topic Subtitle 1   paragraph text 1
Irrelevant Irrelevant    Topic title 1   Topic Subtitle 1   paragraph text 2
Irrelevant Irrelevant    Topic title 1   Topic Subtitle 2   paragraph text 1
Irrelevant Irrelevant    Topic title 1   Topic Subtitle 2   paragraph text 2
Irrelevant Irrelevant    Topic title 2   Topic Subtitle 1   paragraph text 1
Irrelevant Irrelevant    Topic title 2   Topic Subtitle 1   paragraph text 2
Irrelevant Irrelevant    Topic title 2   Topic Subtitle 2   paragraph text 1
Irrelevant Irrelevant    Topic title 2   Topic Subtitle 2   paragraph text 2
```

I'm new to XQuery and XPath but I already understand the basics on how to navigate through nodes and select the ones I need. What I don't know yet is how to work with consecutive data that I want to convert to a nested XML or table (CSV?). Can anyone help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can transform the flat XML into a nested one using `tumbling window` (https://www.w3.org/TR/xquery-30/#id-windows) e.g.

```
for tumbling window $w in title/subtitle/*
    start $t when $t instance of element(topic)
return
    <topic
        title="{$t/@att}">
        {
            for tumbling window $content in tail($w)
                start $c when $c/@att = 'TopicSubtitle'
            return
                <subtopic
                    title="{$c/@att}">
                    {
                        tail($content) ! <para>{node()}</para>
                    }
                </subtopic>
        }
    </topic>
```

gives

```
<topic title="TopicTitle">
    <subtopic title="TopicSubtitle">
        <para>paragraph text 1</para>
        <para>paragraph text 2</para>
    </subtopic>
    <subtopic title="TopicSubtitle">
        <para>paragraph text 1</para>
        <para>paragraph text 2</para>
    </subtopic>
</topic><topic title="TopicTitle">
    <subtopic title="TopicSubtitle">
        <para>paragraph text 1</para>
        <para>paragraph text 2</para>
    </subtopic>
    <subtopic title="TopicSubtitle">
        <para>paragraph text 1</para>
        <para>paragraph text 2</para>
    </subtopic>
</topic>
```

Based on that I think you can then transform the whole to semicolon separated data with

```
string-join(
<title>
    <subtitle>
        {
            for tumbling window $w in title/subtitle/*
                start $t when $t instance of element(topic)
            return
                <topic
                    title="{$t/@att}"
                    value="{$t}">
                    {
                        for tumbling window $content in tail($w)
                            start $c when $c/@att = 'TopicSubtitle'
                        return
                            <subtopic
                                title="{$c/@att}"
                                value="{$c}">
                                {
                                    tail($content) ! <para>{node()}</para>
                                }
                            </subtopic>
                    }
                </topic>
        }
    </subtitle>
</title>//para ! string-join(ancestor-or-self::* ! (text(), @value, 'Irrelevant')[1], ';'), '&#10;')
```

Comment: This is great. Exactly what I needed. After researching more on tumbling window, I doubt I could have found it myself. It took a little to adapt it to the file I have but it's working now with several nested tumbling windows. Because it seems a little dirty, I wanted to ask, do you know of a better way to do this? I mean, is using Java, Python or another language better for this kind of task? Thank you for your help!

Comment: To me who is mostly doing XSLT (where you could use nested `xsl:for-each-group group-starting-with`) it already feels "dirty" using XQuery but I think these languages are a good choice for dealing with XML. If you are looking for something better structured to convert XML with XQuery to CSV then check https://github.com/CliffordAnderson/XQuery4Humanists/blob/master/05-Generating-JSON-and-CSV.md. As for Python, I don't know Python well enough and even if I knew I think it would then depend on which module you can install.

Comment: With pure Java and the built-in XML classes I think it would require a lot of code, I don't know the Java 8 streaming/grouping well enough to estimate the amount of code it would take there,

Answer (score 1):

Although positional grouping is the most general approach to this kind of problem (that is, tumbling windows in XQuery 3.0+, `for-each-group/@group-starting-with` in XSLT 2.0+, as described by Martin Honnen) I don't think it's strictly necessary here, because you're not actually trying to make use of the hierarchic structure implicit in the data.

Specifically, you are converting one flat structure with implicit hierarchy into another flat structure with implicit hierarchy, and you can do that with something along the following lines:

```
<table>{
    for $para in title/subtitle/content[@att='paragraph']
    return <row>
      <cell>irrelevant</cell>
      <cell>irrelevant</cell>
      <cell>{$para/preceding-sibling::topic[1]/string()}</cell>
      <cell>{$para/preceding-sibling::content[@att='TopicSubtitle'][1]/string()}</cell>
      <cell>{$para/string()}</cell>
    </row>
}</table>
```